# Error While Uploading Data Via Dataloader :Too many retries of batch save in the presence of Apex triggers with failures:

Tags: data-loader, data

I am Getting this Error While Uploading Data by Dataloader.

```
Too many retries of batch save in the presence of Apex triggers with failures: when triggers are present partial save requires that some subset of rows save without any errors in order to avoid inconsistent side effects from those triggers.
```

Comment: This error is related to Salesforce 'Bulk DML Exception Handling'. Here is a link to Salesforce documentation concerning this issue. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_bulk_exceptions.htm